# How to setup XMPP on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, xmpp

I'm trying to figure out how to setup a XMPP server on EC2.
I've been looking at ejabberd and OpenFire and can't decide which one is best.
I'm also looking for something easy, for a noob in XMPP.
Can you please give me a tutorial or something to guide me on doing this.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openfire would be the best choice for beginners. That is the server i started with and has installed on my Amazon EC2 image.
Very simple setup and configuration, and it has a great admin interface.
Also several plugins are available, (MSN gateway for instance).
Their Spark client is also very good, but you could use any client that supports XMPP.

The installation is plain and simple, and the Ignite realtime site has all the documentation you need.
Also the Smack API is great for developing your own client (i have built and XMPP bot using Smack and Openfire).